# How do I display a video with opencv from bytes?

Tags: c#, video, opencv, byte, emgucv

I'm working on a project in which we use a radio modem to transmit data (video and telemetry) from an unmanned aerial vehicle to a ground station. What we need to do is display the video in real-time and be able to know which frame corresponds to each chunk of telemetry data in C#.

The data is decapsulated to bytes of telemetry and video (mpeg4). As I've got some experience with OpenCV, I'd like to use it to decode, display and grab clicks position from the video. To do so I'm using the OpenCV wrapper for C# called Emgu.

The problem is that OpenCV loads video from a device or from a file and I've got only a callback with some bytes. I've tried writing those bytes to a file and opening this file with OpenCV, but once it gets to the end, I need to reopen it and continue from where it stopped, which generates lag.

Anyone got any idea how to do this?

Comment: Reading out of a file is the same as reading out of a socket, you should be able to just attatch the stream to the reader and it will pretty much be able to read on the fly. Am I miss understanding something?

Comment: I'm receiving the bytes from a callback which is called everytime new chunks of data arrive. Could I just put them on a socket and treat it like a regular file?

Comment: Because you are reading/writing from a stream, you can easily treat your socket stream as if its a file. Remember, when you write/read files you need to use streams. Back when they created the network protocols they were smart and made it easy and familiar. Like I said, grab the network stream and you can write/read all the bytes from it as if its a file. Read some stuff on network programming, because unlike a file, there is no "end of stream" until you disconnect. If you want to process data on the fly, one thread grabs data and another analyses it so things are in real time.

Comment: Ok, I'll read more about sockets and try to figure how I can solve this problem using them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some helpful links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_socket

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/theory.html

Hope that helps!