# How to detect faces from a video file

Tags: c#, face-detection

We are working on a project where we would like to extract the faces from a video. We found many articles on face-detection of live webcam video, but we need face detection from a already saved video on disk. It must be written in C#.
Input : A video file on hard-disk
Output : Extract all faces and save them in a directory from that file

Comment: Did you try anything to develop your own project? Of you just looking a solution to work for you?

Comment: load video file as stream and use article for live webcam

Comment: Yeah!! I found same thing somewhere, it's on google.

Comment: Use http://www.emgu.com/ library

Comment: Check the list on http://www.facedetection.com/facedetection/software.htm

Comment: Detection of skin color in color images is a very popular and useful technique for face detection. You should read material about that techniques

Comment: We have detected faces from images and live stream video using open cv but could not find any suitable thing to detect from already saved videos.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use OpenCV for C#, go to following links:

http://www.emgu.com 
 https://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp
 https://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet

And read this: [How do I display a video with opencv from bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317143/how-do-i-display-a-video-with-opencv-from-bytes)